# How can I measure the curvature of bird's beak on the field?

Tags: ornithology, measurement, morphometry

I'm wondering if there is a standard tool to measure the bird's beak curvature.

It seems that a [spherometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherometer) wouldn't work because the beaks that I'm measuring are not circular but more parabolic.

I guess something like this:

[image]

I feel that this can be a problem if your birds have different beak length.

What do you think?

Comment: There are possibly infinite superlinear curves that may denote beak morphology. I think what you can use is the maximum slope of the curve. That would generally tell you how curvy is the beak compared to a linear one.

Comment: I was thinking about a tool that I can bring with me on the field. Not something to calculate after with photos or something else. Is this what you propose?

Comment: Yes I was suggesting something like that. I am not aware of any tool like that. You can perhaps measure the actual beak length using a measuring tape and divide it by the direct point-to-point length (like displacement) to have an approximation of the curvature. The higher the ratio, the higher would be the curvature. For a semi-circle it would be π/2.

Comment: Bird beak morfology is often studied (try Google scholar). Aren't there any papers describing how they measure it?

Comment: They usually measure it afterwards on photos : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/40039501_Predatory_Functional_Morphology_in_Raptors_Interdigital_Variation_in_Talon_Size_Is_Related_to_Prey_Restraint_and_Immobilisation_Technique/figures?lo=1

Comment: Another good one is this: http://redpath-staff.mcgill.ca/hendry/Foster2007JEB21,263.pdf. But I'm thinking something more practical on the field.